# Firebase Database throws error: "permission_denied" / Swift / Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the error in the console:

> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] setValue: or removeValue: at /users/lKW2MLmXvCbyku4teSwSMS9Snwq2 failed: permission_denied

when I run this code:

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: eMailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (data, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            guard let newUser = data?.user else { return }
            let uid = newUser.uid
            print("User: \(String(describing: newUser.email)) wurde erstellt, ID: \(String(describing: newUser.uid))")
            
            //Database
            
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
            print("Datenbank ID: \(ref)")
           
            ref.setValue(["fullname" : self.fullNameTextField.text!, "username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email" : self.eMailTextField.text!])
```

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: Can you also add your database permissions from Firebase console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the user doesn't have permission to write to that location in the database. Access to the database is controlled by Firebase's server-side security rules, and you'll need to grant the user the permissions they need.

See the Firebase documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

The minimum change to allow this write operation will be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "lKW2MLmXvCbyku4teSwSMS9Snwq2": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although more likely you want users to be able to write their own node, which would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more on the latter, see the documentation on [content owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).